# jQuery: Rebind default form action after unbind?

Tags: jquery, forms, unbind

In my form, I have bound a function to form submission:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // Bind the submission to the form
            $('form').bind('submit', onsubmit_action);
        });
```

In onsubmit_action() I unbind the submit event so people can't click again, and call preventDefault on the event because I'm doing some AJAX nonsense:

```
        function onsubmit_action(event) {
            if (initiator == "form.buttons.finish") {
                $('form').unbind('submit', onsubmit_action);
                event.preventDefault();
                sendRequest();
            } else {
                this.submit();
            }
        }
```

The function sendRequest() is doing the real AJAX work here.  If sendRequest fails, I simply rebind the form and all is well. But if it succeeds, I need to rebind the form, but not to the onsubmit_action() but instead to the original action of the form:

```
<form action="/carry_on" method="post"></form>
```

the sendRequest() method & its handler:

```
handleResponse = function(data, code, jqXHR) {

switch (data.status) {
    case "SUCCESS":
        // This doesn't work because "submit" is unbound
        $('#form-buttons-finish').click();
        // Same with this
        $('form').submit()
        break;

    case "ERROR":
        alert('error')
        break;

    case undefined:
        alert('undefined');
        break;

    default:
        alert("Some kind of horrible error occurred: " + data.status);
        break;
    }
};

sendRequest = function() {

// Poll the the server for a response
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: "false",
    url: "/json/get_status",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { ref_token: token },
    success: handleResponse,
    error: handleError
});
};
```

What I'm looking to do is rebind the form's submit event, but bind it to the default action of the form: /carry_on and not the onsubmit_action function.  I'm thinking I need to do something like:

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
 post(this.action, this.serialize(), null, "script");
});
```

or something. (I'm guessing on the above syntax)  Any helpful ideas are appreciated.

---

There was something else interfering with my submit.  The form is still actually bound to its default action, since I only unbound the onsubmit_action.

Sorry for the noise.  I would, however, like feedback on my last suggestion about using post().  Also, what would you do HAD the default action been unbound?

Answer (score 0):

I think `.data('events')` lists all bound events on an element set. Perhaps you can get that, find the submit event handle, and cache it for later rebinding?

Found it while Googling around here: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/things-you-may-not-know-about-jquery/

Comment: First, that page is great.  Second, using .data('events') I was able to determine that something else was wrecking my day, because I could see that the default action was STILL bound.  Thanks for this link and taking the time to read.

Answer (score 0):

The code here binds and event handler to the link, there is no unbind() but a simple switch and a [jQuery data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/), my_process() should set 'status' to 'normal'.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('a').bind('click', function(e){
        var status = $(this).data('status');
        switch(status){
            case 'processing':
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).data('status', 'processing');
                break;
            case 'normal':
                break;
            default: /* First click */
                e.preventDefault();
                my_process($(this));  
        } /* end of switch */
    });/* end of bind() */
});/* end of ready() */
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/etuqig/4/edit

### The logic of the event handler

Using the data() function, it detects the link state and acts accordingly:

1. If it's triggered for the first time:

   - It fires our custom function
   - It does a prevent default
2. If it's triggered while our custom function is working

   - It does a prevent default
3. It's triggered after our function finished

   - It does nothing, and the default behaviour happens